# Linux: How to find the physical address of an executable's .text, .data, etc

Tags: c, linux, memory, kernel

I'm working on a project and am not making the progress I would like.

My goal is to add code to, and then recompile, the Linux kernel to display the *physical* address of where the kernel places the various sections of an executable, such as the .text and .data sections, as well as the heap and the stack.

I understand how memory works, such as virtual vs. physical memory, and that it uses pages and lookup tables to translate between the two, but I can't find *where* in the actual code that it does this.

FWIW, I'm working with kernel version 2.6.32.67.

Currently, I'm poking around in `exec.c` and using `printk()` to print out data.  For example, this is the output of the `mm_struct` that is contained in the `struct linux_bprm *bprm` struct (more specifically, in the `mm_struct` of the `vm_area_struct`.)

```
Execing: ./test.out

  bprm
    vm_start:       0x7ffe7ed9b000
    vm_end:         0x7ffe7edb1000
    vm size:        0x16000
 bprm->vma->vm_mm:
    total_vm:       0x3c
    locked_vm:      0x0
    shared_vm:      0x24
    exec_vm:        0x21
    stack_vm:       0x16
    reserved_vm:    0x0
    start_code:     0x400000
    end_code:       0x400744
       code size:   0x744
    start_data:     0x600748
    end_data:       0x600938
       data size:   0x1f0
    start_brk:      0xc66000
    brk:            0xc66000
       brk size:    0x0
    start_stack:    0x7ffe7edaeac0
    arg_start:      0x7ffe7edb04c1
    arg_end:        0x7ffe7edb04c9
    env_start:      0x7ffe7edb04c9
    env_end:        0x7ffe7edb0ff0
```

From here, I am having trouble moving forward.  Does anyone have any guidance?  Thanks.

Comment: `virt_to_phys` from `asm/io.h`

Comment: Note that the memory of a process can be scattered all over the physical memory and even the swap. So, there will not be a single, direct 1:1 mapping for virt to phys. It can even change if a page is swapped out and then loaded to a different physical address. So, any value you get might not reflect the state you use it. And to get a consistent snapshot of the mapping will be virtually impossible.

Comment: Thanks for the followup.  I'd used `virt_to_phys` but it just seemed to add 0x7800000000 to everything and not much else.  ie. If I ran 3 programs, they all had the same virtual and physical address, which didn't seem right.

That makes sense on it being swapped in and out of physical memory and how it would constantly change.  That said, is there a way to keep tabs on where it is _currently_?

Comment: each system will have a different virt_to_phys floor.  Below this is the kernel itself :)